# Is this a topological sort?

Tags: c++, sorting

I am trying to implement topological sort. The idea is that I have a vector of pairs in which the first element is indegree and the second is a linked list. I tried a bunch of tests, they seem to work, but I am not really sure about my implementation. Is this really a topological sort? Can you please review my code and give some advice on how to improve it?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <vector>
#include <stack>

using namespace std;

class Graph {
public: 
    Graph(int V) {
        this->V = V;
        adj.resize(V);
    }

    void addEdge(int from, int to) {
        adj[from].second.push_back(to);
    }

    void FillIndegrees() {
        for (int i = 0; i < adj.size(); ++i) {
            for (int v : adj[i].second) {
                adj[v].first++;
            }
        }
    }

    void PrintIndegrees() {
        for (int i = 0; i < adj.size(); ++i) {
            cout << adj[i].first << endl;
        }   
    }

    void TopologicalSort() {

        FillIndegrees();

        stack<int> st;

        // find zero indegree and add it to a stack
        for (int i = 0; i < adj.size(); ++i) {
            if (adj[i].first == 0) {
                st.push(i);
            }
        }

        while (!st.empty()) {
            int idx = st.top();
            cout << idx << " ";
            st.pop();
            for (int v : adj[idx].second) {
                adj[v].first--;
                if (adj[v].first == 0) {
                    st.push(v);
                }
            }
        }

    }

private:
    int V;
    // indegree, list of edges
    vector<pair<int, list<int>>> adj;
};

int main() {

    Graph g(4);
    g.addEdge(0, 1);
    g.addEdge(0, 2);
    g.addEdge(1, 3);
    g.addEdge(2, 3);

    // Graph g(6); 
    // g.addEdge(5, 2); 
    // g.addEdge(5, 0); 
    // g.addEdge(4, 0); 
    // g.addEdge(4, 1); 
    // g.addEdge(2, 3); 
    // g.addEdge(3, 1); 

    g.TopologicalSort();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Undeclared identifier: stack. Please post your actual, complete, compilable code.

Comment: Since topological sort is a well-known topic, you should try your code with the standard test cases that other people have already thought out. After that test has succeeded, you can remove the question mark from the title, then your code is ready for review. Right now it is off-topic because "the author is reasonable sure that the code works" does not apply.

Comment: Please include any include headers you use in the code as well as any statements like `using namespace std;`.

Comment: This question was posted on Stack Overflow first https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62029149/is-this-a-topological-sort.

Comment: The main does not look like anything would be shown.

Comment: Added headers and using namespace. Also about duplicate. Post on stackoverflow was posted by me and it was claimed off topic, because more appropriate place for it here

Comment: "I tried a bunch of tests, they seem to work" Do you have more tests than currently shown in `main`? Could you add those?

Comment: I added one more, I tried others but this is only one that I still have. Thank you